# How to create a popup radiobutton scroll view in Android?

Tags: java, android, radio-button, android-scrollview

Hi i am trying to make an app and i have trouble with this:
 When i press a button i want a small windows to show (not shure if i have to use popup) in     wich i want to have a scrollview full with radiobuttons and to be able to select one of them. During the scrolling i want to be able to see the backround that was before the popup. When selected a radio button the window should be closed. The scroll view should be vertical.

The code ive came up with uses a new activity ... and that hieds the background which i dont want to happen.

One more thing i want to ask is do i have to go through all my radiobuttons using a switch and case or can i combine it with a for loop?

Many tahnks in advance!

Comment: Consider to use spinner instead of your initial approach. I think that with spinner or custom spinner you can achieve all functionalities what you need.

Comment: Try PopupWindow. would be helpful for your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you will find the answer :)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: Hi, we should avoid answers with just a link. Or see how to reference it correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing. Anyway, thanks for answer and welcome on SO.